# How to add telephone number to the Sales Order Grid using an observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, order-grid

In the Order Grid, I want to add the telephone number which customers used in order -> shipping or billing. I can add the title in the grid but I don't know how get the phone number.

The event that I am using for this is `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` however I can't get order id using this.

Here is my code.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Elavarasan_OrderGrid>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Elavarasan_OrderGrid>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <ordergrid>
        <class>Elavarasan_OrderGrid_Helper</class>
      </ordergrid>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <ordergrid>
        <class>Elavarasan_OrderGrid_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>ordergrid_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </ordergrid>
    </models>
    <events>
      <core_block_abstract_to_html_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>ordergrid/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>getGrid</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>

      <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>ordergrid/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>addPhoneNo</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Elavarasan_OrderGrid_Model_Observer
{

            public function getGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
                if ($block->getId() == 'sales_order_grid') {
                    $block->addColumnAfter(
                            'telephone',
                            array(
                                    'header'   => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Telephone No'),
                                    'align'    => 'left',
                                    'type'     => 'options',
                                    'options'  => $paymentMethods,
                                    'index'    => 'telephone',
                                    'filter_index' => 'telephone.telephone'
                            ),
                            'shipping_name'
                    );

                    //$block->sortColumnsByOrder();

                }

            }

            public function addPhoneNo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
              echo $phone = $observer->getOrder()->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();

            }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A stock sales order grid for Magento 1.9 will prepare its collection in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::_prepareCollection`, and it won't do much out of the box. In fact the base query for the collection is very simple:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
```

So in your 2nd observer method you will have to add order addresses to the collection before you can render them in the grid:

```
public function addPhoneNo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    ...
    $observer->getCollection()->addAddressFields();
    // Use below if you want to inspect the query
    // Zend_Debug::dump($observer->getSelect()->assemble());
    ...
}
```

Now you're able to build your column in the first observer:

```
public function getGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    ...
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

    if ($block->getId() == 'sales_order_grid') {
        $block->addColumnAfter(
            'telephone',
            array(
                'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Telephone No'),
                'align'         => 'left',
                'type'          => 'text',
                'index'         => 'telephone',
                'filter_index'  => 'shipping_o_a.telephone',
            ),
            'shipping_name'
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice the `filter_index` used. You're actually pulling the shipping address phone number as written to the `sales_order_flat_address` table. You can optionally use `billing_o_a.telephone` if desired (use the `Zend_Debug::dump` statement in my example of the columns available on the query result.

Answer (score 0):

**For add telephone number in sales order grid**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinleft(
        array("sales_flat_order_address" => $prefix."sales_flat_order_address"),
        "sales_flat_order_address.parent_id = main_table.entity_id",
        array("telephone" => "telephone")
    )->distinct('main_table.entity_id');
$collection->addFilterToMap("telephone","`sales_flat_order_address`.`telephone`"); // help for filter
```

Comment: But when I add this column in _prepareColumns

then I am getting blank why ?

 $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('telephone'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'telephone',
        ));